# C# D3 (Dynamic Data Display) Charting Project

Tags: c#, charts, dynamic-data-display

Anybody knows why [Dynamic Data Display](http://dynamicdatadisplay.codeplex.com/) is not maintained anymore ? 
D3 is an awesome piece of open source work for c# charting with robust abilities (handles very large datasets & smart data mapping among many others) and it is highly customizable.
Unfortunately the forums seems to have died & the team is not responding anymore, despite the relatively considerable user community.

Answer (score 2):

It seems as though D3 has been picked up by Microsoft Research and is being developed there now. There's a few "branches" of D3 on Codeplex.

- [DynamicDataDisplay](http://dynamicdatadisplay.codeplex.com/)
- [D3Future](http://d3future.codeplex.com/)
- [D3 Community Development](http://d3commdev.codeplex.com/)

If you can't find what you're looking for on the main D3 website, it is definitely recommended that you take a look at the other two. They are not as expansive, but each include their own separate projects that may give you what you need, or at least a push in the right direction.

Also, I have been on the D3 discussions lately, and they are still regulated, although not nearly as frequently as years past.